# Visual Studio 2013 ignoring breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

Going mad here!

Visual Studio is ignoring breakpoints, skipping with a "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different from the original version" alert and the breakpoint turns white.

Simple test - new WinForms project with a few lines in the form load event.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Console.WriteLine("1")
    Console.WriteLine("2")
    Console.WriteLine("3")
End Sub
```

Set a breakpoint on any of those lines, I get the above error, the console outputs as expected (1/2/3) and the form loads with no pause break.

Fresh boot of PC makes no difference.

Running VS 2013, Update 4, on Windows 7 x64.

Jim

Comment: Try a clean solution/Rebuild solution

Comment: Try putting break points at operation based codes like assignments or decision making and all. see if that works and rebuild the solution

Comment: Happens to me too sometimes. Reloading the project without terminating it usually works as a solution for me.

Comment: Rebuild/reload suggestions aren't relevant, as it happens on a clean, new project (load VS > new project > insert code > set BP's > fails)

Comment: Tried a variable assignment, same thing happens

Comment: Tried targeting different .Net frameworks (clutching at straws from other forum posts), no difference.

Comment: @Jim Make sure your application is set to `Debug` and not `Release`. There should be a drop-down at the top ribbon in VS13 that will let you choose the configuration you want. You can also right-click on the project (not the solution) in Solution Explorer and choose properties. Click on Build on the left-hand side and you will have the ability to do it there too.

Comment: Not sure if it's connected, when compiling for x64, I get:

Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4" and architecture "x64".  Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the required executable "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" exists and can be run.

Lots of web information on how to ignore the error, but I don't like ignoring errors that are there for a reason!

Comment: I have two machines with VS 2013 (work and home), the work machine will obey breakpoints correctly, the home machine is the one causing the problem. So at this point thinking it's either a setting somewhere or a corrupted installation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to run the unit test via a test agent. This does not allow debugging to occur. I changed my testsettings.settings file so that the role read "local" instead of remote, and then I was able to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across same problem. I rebuild my solution and checked `Warnings`. There were several warnings, one was of reference missing, due to which break point was ignored. As i fixed the reference missing warning, it started working.